# Export html table to excel file open security warning issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery plugin tableExport.jquery.plugin to export html table.
Plugin is working fine.
I am using excel 2007.

Issue:
When I open Exported file it says
The file you are trying to open is in different format than specified by the file extension.etc

When I say yes it open the file and I can see my content.
But I don't need to see the warning that is coming up after opening.

```
// For BIFF .xls files
 var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;filename=exportData.xls;' + base64data;

 // For Excel 2007 and above .xlsx files
 // var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-
 officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;filename=exportData.xls;' + base64data;
```

I tried both above methods but It never worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove this warning if you are using jquery plugin or any plugin which export html as excel.

Its excel ability to open an HTML table in excel. Since file extension is .xls and file format is HTML. It will always show you this warning.

Its better to look for javascript library which actually create an xls file otherwise go for server side excel generation if you really want to remove this warning.